# What does "18 Gs apiece" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context, slang

A bored former military platoon first attempt to steal from a wealthy man for whom Carlos
works as security, but come up with only a few hundred thousand dollars. Carlos is also a
the military platoon:

> Sam: What's on the table?
>
> Jackson: 110. Two Rolexes, a Patek, 6-carat ring, chains, 40 grand
> cash.
>
> CARLOS: Wait a minute. I got hit over the head and lost my job for,
> like, **18 Gs apiece**?

What does "18 Gs apiece" mean?

Comment: Probably 18 'grand' (18000 dollars) each.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A "G" is a slang term for a grand or $1000 (Or 1000 of the relevant currency. E.g. £1000 in the UK. I'm not sure which other countries would use this.)

'apiece' means 'each': https://www.google.com/search?q=apiece+definition&rlz=1C1GCEA_enGB872GB872&oq=apiece+definition&aqs=chrome..69i57j0i22i30l9.2577j1j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

So Carlos is saying: "I got hit and fired and we only got $18000 each"

Comment: Single-letter ***G = grand = £1000*** isn't actually all that common in the UK, although the full word ***grand*** is used quite often. Note that there is no "full-word" equivalent to the single-letter usage ***K = £1000*** that's more common in the UK.